# Annotations from custom spring-boot-starter not loading to Spring Boot Application

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I have an issue with starting my SpringBootApplication. I'm new to Spring and already looked at existing questions on StackOverflow, but they didn't help me.

I have an external dependency(custom spring-boot-starter) in my Spring Boot Application builded in Gradle:

```
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This is a general purpose Gradle build.
 * To learn more about Gradle by exploring our Samples at https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/samples
 */

plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version "1.9.21"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
    id("org.openapi.generator") version "7.1.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "com.cinephilia.review"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:3.2.0")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.0")
    implementation("ru.quipy:tiny-event-sourcing-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1")
    implementation("ru.quipy:tiny-mongo-event-store-spring-boot-starter:2.1.1")

    implementation("javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final")
    implementation ("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:2.2.19")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.19")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0")
    runtimeOnly("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-kotlin:1.7.0")
    testImplementation(kotlin("test"))
}


tasks {

    openApiGenerate {
        inputSpec = project.provider { file("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml").absolutePath }
        generatorName = "kotlin-spring"
        apiPackage = "com.cinephilia.review.controller"
        invokerPackage = "com.cinephilia.review.invoker"
        modelPackage = "com.cinephilia.review.model"
        configOptions = mapOf(
            "interfaceOnly" to "true",
            "useTags" to "true"
        )
    }

    compileKotlin {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
        sourceSets.main.get().kotlin.srcDirs(
            file("src/main/kotlin"),
            file("${layout.buildDirectory.get()}/generate-resources/main/src/main/kotlin")
        )
        compilerOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }

    compileJava {
        dependsOn(openApiGenerate)
        sourceSets.main.get().java.srcDirs(
            file("src/main/java"),
            file("${layout.buildDirectory.get()}/generate-resources/src/main/java")
        )
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass.set("com.cinephilia.review.ApplicationKt")
}
```

Tiny-event-sourcing-spring-boot-starter representation in External Libraries(section in Intellij Idea) after building Gradle project:
[image]

Here I have the EventSourcingLibConfig class there. Where declared my beans:

```
// IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
// Implementation of methods is not available

package ru.quipy.config

@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration public open class EventSourcingLibConfig public constructor() {
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun aggregateRegistry(eventSourcingProperties: ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties): ru.quipy.core.SeekingForSuitableClassesAggregateRegistry { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun configProperties(): ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun eventMapper(jsonObjectMapper: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper): ru.quipy.mapper.JsonEventMapper { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun eventSourcingServiceFactory(eventSourcingProperties: ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties, aggregateRegistry: ru.quipy.core.AggregateRegistry, eventMapper: ru.quipy.mapper.JsonEventMapper, eventStore: ru.quipy.database.EventStore): ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun eventStreamManager(eventSourcingProperties: ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingProperties, aggregateRegistry: ru.quipy.core.AggregateRegistry, eventStore: ru.quipy.database.EventStore): ru.quipy.streams.AggregateEventStreamManager { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun jsonObjectMapper(): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper { /* compiled code */ }

    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnBean @org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean public open fun subscriptionManager(eventStreamManager: ru.quipy.streams.AggregateEventStreamManager, aggregateRegistry: ru.quipy.core.AggregateRegistry, eventMapper: ru.quipy.mapper.JsonEventMapper): ru.quipy.streams.AggregateSubscriptionsManager { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

So, I have my own spring configuration where I declare `@Autowired` properties:

```
package com.cinephilia.review.config

import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.CommentAggregate
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.CommentAggregateState
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.RatingAggregate
import com.cinephilia.review.aggregates.RatingAggregateState
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory
import java.util.*

@Configuration
class EventSourcingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var eventSourcingServiceFactory: EventSourcingServiceFactory

    @Bean
    open fun commentService() = eventSourcingServiceFactory.create<UUID, CommentAggregate, CommentAggregateState>()

    @Bean
    open fun ratingService() = eventSourcingServiceFactory.create<UUID, RatingAggregate, RatingAggregateState>()
}
```

And `application.properties` for Spring App:

```
...
event.sourcing.scan-package=ru.quipy
event.sourcing.auto-scan-enabled=true
event.sourcing.snapshot-frequency=100
...
```

**Problem**: my application couldn't started and failing with error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field eventSourcingServiceFactory in com.cinephilia.review.config.EventSourcingConfig required a bean of type 'ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'ru.quipy.core.EventSourcingServiceFactory' in your configuration.
```

I tried to build demo project which using my custom spring-boot-starter with Maven and everything working. My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.quipy</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Tiny Event Sourcing lib</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.6.21</kotlin.version>
        <tiny.es.version>2.1.1</tiny.es.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.quipy</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiny-event-sourcing-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${tiny.es.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.quipy</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiny-mongo-event-store-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${tiny.es.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I do same things in different build automation systems, but success not coming.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of this error is not correctly instructing Spring to scan your packages for the configuration classes.  Generally tutorials do not spell this out since they create a neatly structured app like this:

```
└── com
    └── acme
        └── project
            ├── EntryPointApp.kt
            ├── config
            │   └── SomeConfig.kt
            └── service
                └── SomeService.kt
```

If `EntryPointApp.kt` is the Spring application, by default the Spring configuration scanner will then look in that class' package below, so it will automatically find `SomeConfig.kt` and `SomeService.kt`.  So you don't need to do anything special.

But I notice that you are scanning `ru.quipy` but not `com.cinephilia.review.config` where `EventSourcingServiceFactory` is configured.

So try adding an annotation

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["com.cinephilia.review.config"])
```

to your entry point application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried to add @ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["com.cinephilia.review.config"]) -- problem remains for me. And Idea tells me "Could not autowire. No beans of 'EventSourcingServiceFactory' type found." warning. I tried to set @ComponentScan(basePackages = ["ru.quipy.config"]) for my configuration this warning dissapers, but when I start application it's failing the same error.

Comment: I don't know.  Can you provide the file tree for your project and the main Spring entry point Kotlin file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["com.cinephilia"]
```

to `EventSourcingConfig` perhaps?

Try to add

```
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = ["com.cinephilia"]
```

to your class with the `main` function.